# What Windows GUI development tools would be best to focus on for learning/mastering? Suggestions/Reasons

Tags: c#, qt, user-interface, mfc, gtk

I am trying to advance my personal skills in several areas including GUI development and I was wondering about tools / libraries currently available. At the company I currently work, most of our applications are MFC based (likely for historical reasons), but newer projects tend to be C# or even GTK based.

I am aware of Qt as well, which seems to have a very good reputation.

Between MFC, Qt, GTK, C#, (and any others I'm missing), what is everyone using and what do they recommend for professional/personal projects, and why?

Are any of these dead in the water / futureless? (ie, is MFC worth learning relative to the others?)

Can anyone say from experience which of these tools gives the most design freedom (Qt, GTK > C#, MFC ?)

I hope this isn't too open-ended and close-worthy. I'm just looking for recommendations on a path to take to learn and improve and have useful workplace (and personal!) skills.

Thanks!

R

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using C#, [Windows Presentation Foundations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130.aspx) is the modern GUI technology. It allows you to build UI for desktop apps, as well as web apps (using Silverlight). WPF separates the graphic design from the UI logic in a way that was not possible before, so you'll also get to learn a new UI development method.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that even Microsoft are heading more and more towards HTML5 + javascript, even for GUI for Windows 8. It might be worth checking out. Using that will be quite platform independent also.

Comment: This has crossed my mind too. But Windows 8 is just a YouTube video at this time, and it's unclear (to me, at least) how HTML can be used as the front end of a desktop app. You'd have to use some special extensions or APIs , and those are obviously not available at this time. But knowing HTML is a good skill to have anyway, because apps are constantly being moved to the web, so +1.

Answer (score 0):

C# is mainly a language, but for what you are asking, I'd suggest WPF and Silverlight (for the MS focused technologies). Outside of that, I'd be looking at things like Adobe AIR.

WPF gives a lot of power and freedom, but it has a semi-heavy resource cost. Silverlight would be useful due to the usefulness for Windows, Web and Windows Phone

Answer (score 0):

Forget MFC, it's obsolete. C# is not a toolkit, it's a programming language. GTK is nice (that's what I use), but its Windows version is less maintained. So if you target Windows platforms, Qt and WPF should be interesting.